# Who went with whom? Lot and Avram

Tags: grammar-dikduk, commentaries, language, parashat-lech-lecha

Genesis 12:4 reads: Vayelech Avram... Avram went according as HaShem had sproken to him, vayelech Lot ito, and Lot went with him. But the next verse reads: Vayikach Avram.. et Lot, and Avram took Lot, vayetzu lalechet, and they went out on their way to... 
Genesis 13:1 again describes both men going on their way, but this time it says Vaya'al Avram... v'Lot imo, and Avram went up, and Lot with him.

*First I would like to know if Lot went with Avram or if Avram did take Lot, or are both statements in line with eachother? Secondly I would like to know to what the -o ending in ito and imo is revering to: who is the him in each case; is it Lot or Avram?*

(P.s. if someone could explain me when - in which case - to use עמו or אתו I would appriciate it; both are translateable as 'with him').

Answer (score 1):

Rashi (earlier in Genesis 2:15 and in other places as well) explains that "taking" people often means convincing them through conversation. It's therefore not contradictory to say that Avram "took" Lot, and also to imply that Lot made his own decision to act on Avram's suggestion.

In both cases "with him" has to be referring to Avram, because it already mentions Lot by name ("vLot imo", does *not* translate as something like "with he who was Lot").

Comment: So Lot is the one who's going in both cases and Avram whom he went with, correct? So what makes the description of Lot going ito different from imo ?

Comment: I wonder why the double description was used the first time to indicate that Lot went with him, but also that Avram took him. While the second time it only says Lot went with him.

Comment: There seem to be some dispuut if Avram was 70 or 75 when Avram left. The Koban Nesanel asks why the verse has to say that Avrhahm "went" two times. First is says that Avraham went. And then, it says that he took Lot with him. That could have been consolodated into one statement! However, with the Rosh's chidush that Avraham went twice (once at 70 with the Lech Lecha command and the Bris Bein Habesarim on the pilot trip and once for good at age 75), the verse makes sense. One "going" refers to the first trip at age 70, and when he went with Lot, that refers to the second trip at age 75.